# clasp compile file not able to import in generated code

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

I have the following typescript files

src/main.ts

```
function main(): void {
    console.log('main');
    hello(); 
}
```

src/other.ts

```
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

which generates the following in my Google App Project
src/main.gs

```
var module = module || { exports: exports };
//import {hello} from "./other";
function main() {
    console.log('main');
    (0, other_1.hello)();
}
```

src/other.gs

```
var exports = exports || {};
var module = module || { exports: exports };
exports.hello = void 0;
function hello() {
    console.log('hello world');
}
exports.hello = hello;
```

When I try to run the the `main()` function in `main.gs` I get the following error:
[image]

How can I make imports work in a clasp project?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From `//import {hello} from "./other";` and `(0, other_1.hello)();`, I'm worried that in this case, the reason for your current issue might be due to that Google Apps Script doesn't support `import` yet.
- And also, in the case of Google Apps Script, for example, when `function hello() {console.log("hello world");}` is put into a script file of `other.gs`, this function can be directly called from another script file like `main.gs`.

From these points, how about the following modification patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

##### `main.ts`

```js
function main(): void {
  console.log("main");
  hello();
}
```

##### `other.ts`

```js
function hello(): void {
  console.log("hello world");
}
```

- By this modification, when `main` is run, `console.log("main")` in `main` function and `console.log("hello world")` in `hello` function are run with the script editor of Google Apps Script.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the Class object is used.

##### `main.ts`

```js
import { Sample } from "./other";

function main(): void {
  console.log("main");
  new Sample().hello();
}
```

##### `other.ts`

```js
export class Sample {
  public hello(): void {
    console.log("hello world");
  }
}
```

- By this modification, when `main` is run, `console.log("main")` in `main` function and `console.log("hello world")` in `hello` function are run with the script editor of Google Apps Script.

Comment: Both options work, however Pattern 1 shows an error locally in my IDE, whereas Pattern 2 works correctly in both. FYI I modified Pattern 2 to have `hello()` be a static function, that way I don't need to create an instance.

Comment: @sheamus Thank you for replying and additional information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.